# Migrating Wordpress to Hugo (or generic markdown)

Tags: wordpress, cms, migration, code, markdown

I have a blog which I want to migrate from Wordpress to Hugo.

The problem is that the blog has a lot of posts which contain code examples, including HTML code.

I'm using [Codecolorer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codecolorer) as Wordpress plugin, so my posts look something like this (my problem shouldn't be specific to this plugin though):

```
text 
[cc lang="html"]
<input type="text" value="value">
<input type="text" value="value">
[/cc]
more text [cci]<div>inline code[/cci]
```

I would like this to be transformed to valid markdown automatically (or at least semi-automatically; if I have to fix some issue manually, that would be fine). Ideally, the export is in a format that I can then directly import to Hugo.

I tried the plugin [wordpress-to-hugo-exporter](https://github.com/SchumacherFM/wordpress-to-hugo-exporter)
, but it mangles the code completely.

I tried replacing the `[cc ...]` tags with `<code>` as well as `<xmp>` tags in the database before using the exporter plugin, but that resulted in completely empty posts.

I also tried using the [Jekyll Exporter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jekyll-exporter/) (it produces a broken ZIP), [exitwp](https://github.com/thomasf/exitwp) (with and without replaced `[cc]` tags, but it mangles the code or removes it completely), and [wp2md](https://github.com/dreikanter/wp2md) (it removes the code).

Is there a way to easily transform Wordpress posts which contain example code to markdown which can then be imported to Hugo?

Comment: i think there is no automated system but you can convert your sort code in <code></code> by MYSQL that is easy to do after that you can migrate to hugo

Comment: @ShivSingh You mean the same way I tried replacing it with `<xmp>`? I actually tried that as well, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Just export your WP database and open by any editor and do replace it, and it will sure work.